# repair disk - unmounted encrypted disk partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, startup, repair

In Yosemite 10.10.2 after verifying my startup disk in disk utility I got this message...

"This disk needs to be repaired using the Recovery HD. Restart your computer, holding down the Command key and the R key until you see the Apple logo. When the OS X Utilities window appears, choose Disk Utility."

As per instructed I rebooted in recovery mode and tried to repair the disk from there. The problem is that in recovery mode my startup partition shows up as "unmounted encrypted disk partition", and all options including verify and repair are greyed out. The core storage volume can be repaired but it comes up clean.

What do I do, is this problematic? My computer appears to be running smoothly in general, I just verified the disk out of curiosity and now I'm faced with this issue.

Comment: do you have such a thing as encrypted disk partition?

Answer (score 1):

If your main partition is encrypted it will not be unlocked and mounted after booting to Recovery Mode.

After starting Disk Utility you have to unlock the volume first. Then enter the FileVault2 password. The volume will be mounted automatically after entering the proper password.

[image]

Now verify or repair your main volume.

Comment: How do i know the password is it what I use to sign in to my computer?

Comment: @user1324925 Usually you get this message if you have encrypted your disk previously with FileVault2. The password may be your account password or a special one if you encrypted it with a different password. You may of course try your account password.